# This declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked with '@kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi' or '@OptIn(kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading to React Native 0.70.6 I keep getting this issue on android, haven't found a solution for days.

```
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/hugohouyez/code/hugoh1995/Superprof/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/facebook/react/tasks/BundleHermesCTask.kt: (137, 11): This declaration is experimental and its usage must be marked with '@kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi' or '@OptIn(kotlin.ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)'
```

I've installed "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.10", in my package.json even tho it's not mentioned in the docs because without it it would says it could not find the dependency.

build.graddle

```
...
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 7):

Change to the distributionUrl in /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties fixed the issue for me.

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
```